# Jquery $().load subtracts information from PHP $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am reloading a `<div>` with the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#commentrefresh").load("commentright.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#commentrefresh").load('commentright.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 9000);
});
```

At the same time I am including  a PHP file e.g. www.mysite.nl/someotherpage in my main page with:

```
$site = $_GET['site'];
include_once($site);
```

This is not in the `<div>` that I want to be refreshed.

Both separately work fine, but as soon as I use them both together, the `<div>` with `$site` is being refreshed on and on. I guess the jQuery request is not specific enough.
Is there a way to change the script to make sure only the right `<div>` gets refreshed?

Comment: Ids of divs are unique right?

Comment: Using the (unique!) ID of an element should always be specific enough as selector so I'd also recommend to check for duplicate IDs. Type `$('#commentrefresh')` in the console tab of Firefox or Chrome and check the length property of the object returned, if you'll get "2" you have a dupe.

Comment: Yes. 
They are unique , this is why I wonder why it does not work properly.

Comment: It could be useful to see the relevant part of your markup...

Comment: I do not think it is relevant, if I take a look in the console, I see that the div is filled with the content of the $site value, not with the content of commentright.php. 
So the problem is the conflict in the PHP get value getting into the javascript load.

Comment: Maybe usefull I read the content of the  `$site` as mysite.nl/index.php?site=someotherpage.php in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've solved the problem myself.
What happened was that the .htaccess rewrote the server request to www.mysite.nl/index.php?commentright.php.php .

So into the

```
<div id="commentrefresh">
```

the total page appeared.

I put the line :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/commentright.php      /commentright.php
```

at the beginning of the rewriterules and now it works properly.